# Lightswitch IIS 7.5 Deployment - GetAuthenticationInfo

Tags: iis, deployment, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am having an absolute nightmare with the "Load operation failed for query 'GetAuthenticationInfo'. [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]" error when deploying my applications to a new server.

The apps I have are working and have been running for a while on another server. I have now got to move them to a new one, and I cannot get anything to work!

I have been through all of the posts on this error and have tried almost everything to get this deployment working.

Old Server: Win 2008 R2

New Server: Win 2008 R2

At first I thought it had something to do with Devexpress Xtra reports but I have disproved that by creating a bare bones app with one screen and one table and no extentions. And it still fails. I have also tried this with every combination of authentication. I have also deployed this test app to the old server and it all works fine, so I am sure there must be something wrong with my IIS settings. Visual studio is publishing the app with no errors. I only get it on runtime. I have tried to use fiddler to get a clue as to what is going on but I cant find anything useful.

I have also tried:

•   removing and adding the web server role on the new server to try and reset configurations.

•   Deploying several known working LS applications

•   Every combination of Authentication on the IIS server for the app, website and server level

•   Tried syncing the IIS configuration with the old server using MSdeploy.exe cmd line

•   Repairing the .NET Framework 4 Client prile & extended

•   restarting the server

•   Installing updates

•   re installing web deploy

•   Made sure the application pool was .net v4

•   made sure the application pool was integrated

•   changed the authentication on app pool user to a domain account with known admin rights to the server (and have now put back to apppool identity)

•   Creating a new website and deploying the app into there

•   restarting web services

•   Installing Lightswitch 2012 Server pre-requisites

None of these have worked at all.

The only way I can get my deployed application to load into a screen is to buid as a web type and change the url from

```
http://server/otm
```

to

```
http://server/otm/default.htm?IsLaunchedByVS=True&AuthenticationType=None
```

Something which I think it could be related to is a faulty installation of "Lightswitch Server Configuration" which installed using the Web Platform Installer 4.5
This however is not showing in the Add/Remove programs list, so I cannot uninstall it to see if it is messing things up. I cant seem to uninstall it from the WPI and i also cant find a direct download link from Microsoft.

I am completley out of ideas and in big trouble as these are production applications and the old serve will be shut down within the next two weeks. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that it's only this *one* application that won't run on the *new* server? And that the application works OK on the *old* server?

Comment: No I have tried deploying a few lightswitch applications, and I even made a barebones LS app with no 3rd party extensions and even that wouldn't work. I tried deploying all of these apps to the old server and it worked fine. This is why I believe there is something wrong with the new servers IIS configuration. But I cannot find any solution after looking on the internet for days.

Comment: Thanks. It was the combination of what worked where that I was interested in. I agree that it would appear to be the configuration of the web server on the new machine that's the problem. Have you seen this article, written by one of the LS team? [Diagnosing Problems in a Deployed 3-Tier LightSwitch Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/09/20/diagnosing-problems-in-a-deployed-lightswitch-application-eric-erhardt.aspx). I create desktop applications, so diagnosing web problems is not my forte, so hopefully the article will help.

Comment: If the article doesn't help, post a question to the official LightSwitch MSDN forum, stating what you've tried, & if you don't get an answer there, I'll try to ping someone on the LS team for you.

Answer (score 0):

.net framework 4.5 try running the app on .net framework 4 I had the issue and spent 40 hours on it .net 4 framework works

Comment: I am not running on .NET 4.5 it is 4. I have seen the articles about the app pool being v4 not v2 which I have made sure of. I have also repaired the .NET Client as suggested but it made no difference.